# Can I run php code from A url that is generate from Cmd?

Tags: php, cmd

In the `Frameworks` like `symfony` you can run php code `without any software` from `cmd` you write `php bin/console server:run` after you run this command it generate URL like  `http://127.0.0.1:8000` Can I run php code from A URL that is generate from Cmd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a [Built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) since 5.4.0:

Linux:

```
/path/to/php -S 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Windows:

```
c:\path\to\php -S 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Will yield:

```
PHP 5.6.5 Development Server started at Thu Jul 27 10:46:10 2017
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080
Document root is C:\tmp
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

As shown, the web server document root will be the directory you ran the command from.